# Is there a way to programmatically set a dataset's schema from a .csv

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

As an example, I have a `.csv` which uses the Excel dialect which uses something like Python's csv module `doubleQuote` to escape quotes.

For example, consider the row below:

```
"XX ""YYYYYYYY"", ZZZZZZ ""QQQQQQ""","JJJJ ""MMMM"", RRRR ""TTTT""",1234,RRRR,60,50
```

I would want the schema to then become:

```
 [
   'XX "YYYYYYYY", ZZZZZZ "QQQQQQ"',
   'JJJJ "MMMM", RRRR "TTTT"',
   1234,
   'RRRR',
   60,
   50
 ]
```

Is there a way to set the schema of a dataset in a programmatic/automated fashion?

Answer (score 3):

While you can do this in code, foundrys dataset-app can also do this natively. This means you can skip writing the code (which is nice) but also means you can potentially save a step in your pipeline (which might save you on runtime.)

After uploading the files to a dataset, press "edit schema" on the dataset:
[image: edit schema button]

Then apply settings like the following, which would result in the desired outcome in your case:

[image: schema editor]

Then press "save and validate" and the dataset should end up with the correct schema:

[image: final dataset]

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this example:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = files
        .sparkSession()
        .read()
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .csv(csvDataset);

output.getDataFrameWriter(dataset).write();
```

Add the `header`, `quote`, and `escape` options, like so:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = files
        .sparkSession()
        .read()
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("quote", "\"")
        .option("escape", "\"")
        .csv(csvDataset);

output.getDataFrameWriter(dataset).write();
```